# Sencha by default adding readonly attribute to 'Ext.field.Number' type

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

After upgrading my application from sencha 2.1.1 to 2.3.1, we got a wired issue. We have the below code to create a number filed.

```
 Ext.create( 'Ext.field.Number', {
              cls: 'timee_1',
              inputCls: 'listitemtitle',
              name: 'itemValue',
              labelWidth:'0',
              minValue: 0,
              clearIcon: false

    })
```

Here is generated HTML of the above number field copied from chrome developer tools.

```
<input class="listitemtitle" type="number" id="ext-element-780" name="itemValue" 
min="0" readonly="false">
```

The readonly atribute is getting added by default. Though it is getting added as 'false', html is not considering it. As per the HTML spec, if readonly is present, it considers that input field as read only irrespective of the value.

This attribute was not added by default in sencha 2.1.1. How to stop adding that attribute by default.

Comment: have you tired by adding explicitly {readOnly : Boolean} config in ur numberfield ??

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution in the framework you're using, but if you don't find it, you could do a jQuery fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").removeAttr("readonly");
});
```

Comment: I thought of removing it... But I am looking for a better solution... To stop adding that.. Rather than removing it.

Comment: Yeah if you can catch it before hand, it's definitely a better solution. Since this solution adds overhead to your initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it both with Sencha Touch 2.2 (good start is try.sencha.com) and with Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Both do not show the readonly flag.

But you can try to set:

```
config: {
    readOnly: undefined
}
```

it seems you are not showing the code where your component of the numberfield is defined.
Inside Ext.field.Number you have a config item:

```
component: {type: number}
```

This component gets or does not get a flag readonly. Usually this is defined in Ext.field.Text within updateReadOnly. Somewhere you might have an overwrite to that class or to the Numberfield.